# Getting "reference is ambiguous and double imported" errors in a simple form

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have following very simple model and a view

package models;

```
import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Safari extends Model {

    public String name;
}
```

views/safari/add.html.scala

```
@(myForm: play.data.Form[Safari])

@helper.form(action = routes.Safari.submit()) {
  @helper.inputText(myForm("username"))
  @helper.inputPassword(myForm("password"))
}
```

I am getting following error after adding the line @(myForm: play.data.Form[Safari]) in the view

reference to Safari is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import controllers._ and import models._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `controllers` and `models` packages are imported by default in your views. Since you have both a controller and a model named `Safari` the compiler doesn't know which one to use for `play.data.Form[Safari]`.

You need to either rename your controller or model to differentiate them or use the full package name in your view.

```
@(myForm: play.data.Form[models.Safari])
```